# awk if with multiple condition throws error

Tags: if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

**Simple Awk with multiple conditions inside if with binary operator. Its is spitting out error.
See the below O/P.**

```
D:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin>bpdbjobs -report -most_columns | awk '{FS=","; if ($2 == 0 || $11 > 0) printf "%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d:%d:%d,%d,%d\n", $7,$5,$6,$4,$8,strftime("%c",$9),strftime("%c", $11),$10/(60*60),$10%(60*60)/60,$10%60,$16,$15}' > c:\bpdbjobs_report_processed.csv
awk: cmd. line:2: {FS=","; if ($2 == 0
awk: cmd. line:2:                      ^ unexpected newline or end of string
'$11' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

A snipped of few lines from input data is as follows...

```
23123,0,0,,xxxxxEX-IS,Daily-Differen-Noon,xxxxxex, ,1374573600,0000007052,0000000000, ,1,,,,,0,,root,1,16,1,9999,root,xxx-abc-nbkp,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,23123,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,,,Drives are in use in storage unit (xxx-abc-nbkp-hcart-robot-tld-0),
23122,17,3,0,,,,,1374566996,0000000035,1374567031,,1,,,,,100,7644,root,,,,,,xxx-abc-nbkp,,,,,,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ,
23121,2,4,0,,,xxx-abc-BANCS1,xxx-abc-nbkp,1374557721,0000022931,0000000000,,1,,,,/backups/rpru/scripts/check_crs_listener.out,0,9628,root,,,,90000,root,xxx-abc-nbkp,,,,0,10,0,0,,,,,,,,,,xxx-abc-nbkp,,,,1,1,,,,,1,,,, ,
23120,0,1,,xxxxxEX-MB-BF,Daily,xxxxxex,xxx-abc-nbkp,1374555781,0000024871,0000000000,xxx-abc-nbkp-hcart-robot-tld-0,1,3,8579904,38000,/Microsoft Exchange Mailboxes/Nisha Jayadas [njayadas]/Top of Information Store/Inbox/FW: xxxxx Final Report for 30 Jun 2013\, 01 Jul 2013 and 02 Jul 2013 ,61,,root,0,16,4,0,other,xxx-abc-nbkp,3,3,0,0,55506,0,0,23120,346,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,xxxxxex_1374555781,1,,,0, ,
```

Comment: You may need to wrap the `if` condition inside a `{}`. So it would be `FS=","; {if...`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.D:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin>bpdbjobs -report -most_columns | awk '{FS
=","; {if ($2 == 0 || $11 > 0) printf "%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d:%d:%d,%d,%d\n", $
7,$5,$6,$4,$8,strftime("%c",$9),strftime("%c", $11),$10/(60*60),$10%(60*60)/60,$
10%60,$16,$15}}' > c:\bpdbjobs_report_processed.csv
awk: cmd. line:2: {FS=","; {if ($2 == 0
awk: cmd. line:2:                       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
'$11' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then, you'd better post some input data so we can check.

Comment: Please format your data for better readability.

Comment: In Windows you need `Windows quotes`, not bash/shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Windows, change your command line:

```
awk -F, "{if ($2 == 0 || $11 > 0) printf \"%s,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d:%d:%d,%d,%d\n\", $7,$5,$6,$4,$8,strftime(\"%c\",$9),strftime(\"%c\", $11),$10/(60*60),$10%(60*60)/60,$10%60,$16,$15}"
```

Comment: captcha, Your answer seems to be guiding me towards an answer. Instead of Windows CMD using the Cygwin Terminal. It seems to work fine. Let me check thoroughly.

Comment: In `Cygwin` the quoting is imo the same as in bash/shell. But the _error message_ `is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` is **Windows**, not Cygwin.